# Geoserver cannot be stopped or started on tomcat

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, apache

I recently tried to create a script to check if my geoserver was running and if not, restart tomcat so that it was running.  I placed the script into the *cron.hourly* folder, however the script was not updating the log file that I created.  My geoserver now will not start back up and I am getting a `java.Nullpointerexception` when I try to do the shutdown command.  The script looked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
STAT=`netstat -na | grep 8765 | awk '{print $7}'`
if [ "$STAT" = "LISTEN" ]; then
cd /home/blair
date >> practice-log.txt
echo "DEFAULT TOMCAT PORT IS LISTENING, SO ITS OK" >> practice-log.txt
elif [ "$STAT" = "" ]; then
cd /home/blair/
date >> practice-log.txt
echo "8765 PORT IS NOT IN USE SO TOMCAT IS NOT WORKING" >> practice-log.txt

############################################################################
cd /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin
sudo ./shutdown.sh
sudo ./startup.sh
fi
RESULT=`netstat -na | grep 8765 | awk '{print $7}' | wc -l`
if [ "$RESULT" = 0 ]; then
cd /home/blair/
echo "TOMCAT PORT STILL NOT LISTENING" >> practice-log.txt
elif [ "$RESULT" != 0 ]; then
cd /home/blair/
echo "TOMCAT PORT IS LISTENINS AND SO TOMCAT WORKING" >> practice-log.txt
fi
```

It is now impossible for me to finish the shutdown command without getting an error message of:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:494)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:370)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:457)

I could really use some help to get this back and running.  Also when trying to start the geoserver using the tomcat webapp manager on the html page I get the FAIL - Application at context path /geoserver could not be started error message.  If anyone has any suggestions they would be extremely useful.

Also I am running tomcat 7 on apache 2 on an ubuntu server.